# Trying to Utime via FTP

Tags: ftp

I am connecting to my server via FTP (that is the only way I have access to this server in particular). I need to utime a command via FTP to the server. Other commands work but when I try something like

```
site for file in *;do utime 20120101084400 ${file}; done;
```

to change all dates in a given directory, I receive an error that says **usage: form format** or **invalid command** depending on the variation of that command I try.

I tried this command (without the site part) on my local unix and it works but not remotely via FTP.

How do I do that? If there's a way to do that recursively it will be a bonus... :)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowed `SITE` commands vary with the FTP daemon in use (like, `SITE CHMOD` in [`vsftpd`](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html); some more in [Apache's FtpServer](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/ftpserver_site_commands.html)).  In general, it's *not the remote shell facility* you seem to expect.
However, ProFTPd apparently [supports `SITE UTIME`](http://proftpd.open-source-solution.org/docs/contrib/mod_site_misc.html#SITE_UTIME).

So if your FTPd in question has `SITE UTIME`, you could try to `SITE UTIME` in a *client-side loop*, like this (pseudo-code, no server mentioned, also keep in mind that there might be spaces (needs quotation); also you'd need a versatile FTP client ([`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) might be a good candidate)):

```
for file in $(./ftp-get-directory-list)
  do ftp-client -c "SITE UTIME ${file}"
done
```

**EDIT** also see [Gilles' nice answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202179/993018) on the possible interaction between Bash scripts and `lftp`.

**Addendum** If you're into some scripting language (e.g. Python), you could also do yourself a favor by [using some FTP library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html).